# Pass member function body as macro parameter

Tags: rust

I am trying to pass the body of a member function as a macro parameter. Is it possible to alter the code below so that it works?

```
macro_rules! iterator{
    ($ty:ty, $ident:ident; $($state_ident:ident: $state_ty:ty), *; $next:block) => (
        struct $ident {                                         // ^ the parameter
            $($state_ident: $state_ty), *
        }

        impl Iterator for $ident {
            type Item = $ty;

            fn next(&mut self) -> Option<$ty> {
                $next // <- cannot refer to 'self' parameter in this block
            }
        }
    );
}

iterator!(i32, TestIterator; index: i32; {
    let value = Some(self.index);
    self.index += 1;
    value
});
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2d8cbe7c2e62769072fad185bf0050c9&version=stable&mode=debug)

Compiler error:

```
error[E0424]: expected value, found module `self`
  --> src/main.rs:18:22
   |
18 |     let value = Some(self.index);
   |                      ^^^^ `self` value is only available in methods with `self` parameter

error[E0424]: expected value, found module `self`
  --> src/main.rs:19:5
   |
19 |     self.index += 1;
   |     ^^^^ `self` value is only available in methods with `self` parameter
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution would be to accept a closure instead of a block:

```
macro_rules! iterator{
    ($ty:ty, $ident:ident; $($state_ident:ident: $state_ty:ty),*; $next:expr) => (
        struct $ident {
            $($state_ident: $state_ty), *
        }

        impl Iterator for $ident {
            type Item = $ty;

            fn next(&mut self) -> Option<$ty> {
                $next(self)
            }
        }
    );
}

iterator!(i32, TestIterator; index: i32; |me: &mut TestIterator| {
    let value = Some(me.index);
    me.index += 1;
    value
});

fn main() {}
```

This requires explicitly passing `self` to the closure. You cannot use the identifier `self` in the closure because `self` is only allowed to be declared in the parameter list of a function.

You'll also need to specify the type of the closure parameter, this is a limitation of closures that are defined as a variable and used later, as opposed to being immediately used.